# Is there a Bower package for Breeze and the Breeze Angular Service?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

is there an official Bower package for Breeze (that also includes the Breeze Angular Service)? I am not using Visual Studio / Hot Towel for my front end development. I have decided that I want to try using Yeoman to create my project and am using Adobe Brackets for the front end. I am using VS2013 and Web API for the backend.

The angular template for Yeoman creates a grunt file that handles all bower components and minifies them for you. Its also easier to manage 3rd party "vendor" scripts with a package manager like Bower (or NuGet).

If a Bower Breeze package (ideally with the Angular Service) does not exist can you let me know if someone is planning to create one (and when that might happen)?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Updated Feb 10, 2015 to reflect the now current packages***

There are OFFICIAL Breeze bower packages available.

```
bower install breeze-client
bower install breeze-client-labs
```

The `breeze-client` package delivers the core Breeze libraries including all adapters.

> ***breeze.bridge.angular.js*** (FKA, "breeze.angular.js") is among the core adapters and provides the "breeze.angular" service you asked about.

The `breeze-client-labs` package has all the current script files from breeze labs such as:

```
breeze.directives.js
breeze.directives.css
breeze.getEntityGraph.js
breeze.metadata-helper.js
```

etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I just published the "official" package as described in my answer ... at about the same time as your comment.

Comment: Downvote because this answer is now misleading. The command referenced will install the deprecated bower package. Best to follow @Mosby's answer.

Comment: Great decision on a down vote for something that was answered almost a year ago...

Comment: Strangely, I do not see breeze-client appear in the VS2015 Bower package manager when searching for `breeze-client`, although the command above works.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an **official breezejs bower package** for *client* assets. Install from a terminal/command window with

`bower install breezejs`

> Case matters! Be sure to spell "breezejs" in all lowercase.

This package contains the core JavaScript distribution files PLUS

- adapters - the officially supported breeze adapters in the core, including the mongo client adapter
- labs - the currently "approved" breeze.labs ... you'll find the *breeze.angular* service module there.

Comment: Downvote because this answer is now misleading. The command referenced will install the deprecated bower package. Best to follow @Mosby's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The former "breeze.js" bower and npm packages have been retired as of January 20, 2014. They are frozen at breeze release v.1.5.2. This repo will be retained indefinitely.

We've separated the breeze core and breeze labs content into their own packages:

```
breeze-client
breeze-client-labs
```

You'll get almost the same effect with

```
bower install breeze-client
bower install breeze-client-labs
```

You'll have to adjust your script tags too because the files have moved around a bit too ... in obvious ways.